# Custom hibernate criteria (one-to-many relationship)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to create custom Hibernate query.

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
    List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
    restrictions.add(builder.equal(user.get("firstname"), user.getFirstName()));
    List<User> users = (List<User>) entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

I need to add to restrictions additional criteria. I have additional model `Photo`, which connected to model `User` with foreign key `user_id`.
I need to find users, which has any photos.

`User` model contains:

```
 private List<Photo> photos;

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "photo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
 @JsonIgnore
 public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
     return photos;
 }
```

Photo model contains:

```
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

**UPDATED**

I need something like this:

```
restrictions.add(builder.isNotNull(user.get("photos")));
```

but it's not working.

Problem is not with how to combine 2 restrictions, problem with how to add restriction isNotNull... User know nothing about photos. Photos know about user as they has user_id.

**UPDATED2**:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

SQL:

```
select * from User user0_ cross join Photo photos1_ where user0_.id=photos1_.user and (. is not null)
```

I need follow SQL:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT user.* FROM user
 LEFT JOIN photo
 ON user.id = photo.user_id;
```

Comment: What exactly is the question / the problem / the error?

Comment: I need something like this:               restrictions.add(builder.isNotNull(user.get("photos")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself. Full code:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
Root<Photo> photo = criteria.from(Photo.class);
List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
restrictions.add(builder.equal(user.get("firstname"), user.getFirstName()));
restrictions.add(builder.equal(user.get("id"), photo.get("user")));

List<User> users = (List<User>) entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
restrictions.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(user.get("firstname"), user.getFirstName()),Restrictions.isNotNull(user.get("photos")));
```

**UPDATE:** The bidirectional relationship you are looking for is something like this:

Photo class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user")
private User user;
```

User class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Set<Photo> photos;
```

In this one you have it mapped both ways so you can access photos from the user and user from photos.

Comment: restrictions.add(builder.isNotNull(user.get("photos"))); it's not working. Problem is not with how to combine 2 restrictions, problem with how to add restriction isNotNull... User know nothing about photos. Photos know about user as they has user_id.

Comment: I think the problem here is that in PostgreSQL User is a reserved word. You have to choose another name for your class. Also, you should mark this question as solved ed eventually asking a new one if the problem persists.

Comment: I've changed User name to another. It's not working anyway. I have same problem. I need to find all User, which has photos.

Comment: I think, I need left join or cross join tables, but without dublicates